# Easiest way of getting the numbers of hits for a keyword off Google programmatically

Tags: php, javascript, json, screen-scraping

I'm writing a **html/javascript/PHP** based **web application** that allows users to type in a random keyword and **get returned the number of hits** that keyword would generate when searched on Google.com

I know this can be achieved by a number of different approaches, what I want though, is the **simplest way of doing this**.

What would you say the **best approach would be** here, if we choose to allow an error marginal of say 2%? Could you show some sample code?

### Approach 1: Screen Scraping

Use PHP and `file_get_contents` like this

```
$keyword = "Football";
$html = file_get_contents("http://www.google.com/?q=" . rawurlencode($keyword));
preg_match('/Results: - \d+ of about ([0-9,]+) for/', $html, $reg);
var_dump($reg[1]);
```

But that doesn't quite do it for me and I guess this would **violate Google's terms of use**? What would the implications of that be?

### Approach 2:  Google Ajax API

Use Google Ajax API and the `estimatedResultsCount` property in JSON. I don't really know how to actually do this so if you argue this would be the better approach, could you please provide me with some **sample code** so I'll get the idea?

Other approaches? What I'm really looking for here are concrete, more precise answers to **what techneques** to use and **how to use them**. Again, please do also provide some sample code for the sake of clarity.

Comment: See the second _MyVodaFone_ answer at this post: https://forums.digitalpoint.com/threads/php-and-json-decode-for-google-api.1640928/ (5 minutes of Googling). Then, when you have a more specific question (errors trying to invoke the API for example) I will be glad to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Go with approach 2, using Google's API.

I'd recommend checking out jQuery, especially the [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) function, and playing around with the API in [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/) at first.